# 27" iMac Serial-ATA in System Report

Tags: macos

I really could use some help figuring out why the Serial-ATA device tree has an extra "Intel 6 Series Chipset" but nothing appears connected.

I am pretty sure I only have one HD and one optical drive - so can someone help me figure this out?

I know there are other ports that are not actively used, but they don't usually appear unless there is a connection, right?

[image: screen capture]

Answer (score 0):

The [mid 2010 27" iMacs](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP588) could have a 3.5" SATA II HDD, as well as a 2.5" SATA HDD or SSD... in addition to the optical drive.  So... you are seeing an unused drive controller that could have another drive connected to it if you so chose to add one.  At the time of purchase, you would have had the option of an HDD or SSD if you wanted the additional space.  the limitation of it being a 2.5" drive is more than likely a physical space constraint.